# Reading raw bytes from an Aztec barcode via AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject yields unexpected result

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, zlib, aztec-barcode

I have been working on an iOS reader app for a special kind of barcode used by Deutsche Bahn (german rail) for a while now. It is a variant of Aztec barcode that concatenates a DSA signature string and a zlib deflated payload.

I was stuck, when I learned that the `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject` had no public method for reading the raw bytes contained in the barcode and the string methods always garbled the zlib-compressed data.

Luckily, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36957666/3625228) sent me in the right direction. The (private) bytes can be accessed with KVO, and as I don't currently expect to distribute the app on the App Store, that was perfect.

Despite my almost non-existent `Swift` and `Objective-C` knowledge I managed to get this to work, as you can see in the sample code. But the bytes from the barcode that are stored in `NSData` don't match the expected result! I suspected the zlib library I use ([DeflateSwift](https://github.com/tidwall/DeflateSwift)) was not working, so I built a test case, which worked fine.

My question is: what am I doing wrong? Do I need to further process the raw bytes to get to the expected result (see below)? How *raw* exactly are the bytes that are stored in the `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject`? Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code (which is a sad mashup of `Swift` and `Objective-C`)

```
if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
    let readableObject = metadataObject as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject;
    let rawReadableObject = readableObject.valueForKeyPath("_internal.basicDescriptor")!["BarcodeRawData"] as? NSData;

    if let rawBytes = rawReadableObject {
       let barcodeData = rawBytes; // or use testData instead

        let barcodeSplit:Int = 68;
        let barcodeLength:Int = barcodeData.length;
        let barcodeHeader:NSData = barcodeData.subdataWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: barcodeSplit))
        let barcodeZlibContent:NSData = barcodeData.subdataWithRange(NSRange(location: barcodeSplit, length: (barcodeLength-barcodeSplit)))

        let count = barcodeZlibContent.length / sizeof(UInt8)
        var array = [UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)
        barcodeZlibContent.getBytes(&array, length:count * sizeof(UInt8))

        print("\(barcodeLength)kb")
        print(barcodeHeader)
        print(barcodeZlibContent)

        var inflater = InflateStream()
        var (inflated, err) = inflater.write(array, flush: true)
        if err != nil{
            fatalError("\(err!)")
        }

        if let ticketString = String(bytes: inflated, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            print(ticketString)
        } else {
            print("not a valid UTF-8 sequence")
        }
    }
}
```

### This is what I get

The bytes returned from `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject` are

`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`

Here is the sample barcode of a Deutsche Bahn ticket I used for testing.
[image: sample Deutsche Bahn Aztec barcode]

### This is what I need

When scanned with a proper barcode reader (I used bcTester 5) this yields the following bytes:

`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`

As you can see, at offset 68 (`78 9C`) begins a valid zlib stream. If you split the data here and inflate the zlib data, it returns a string like this:

`U_HEAD01005300802P9QAN-40501201514560DEDE0080ID0200180104840080BL020357031204GW3HEMP906012015060120151021193517S0010018Fernweh-Ticket natS00200012S0030001AS00900051-0-0S01200010S0140002S2S0150006BerlinS0160011NeumÃ¼nsterS0210038B-Hbf  8:16 ICE794/HH-Hbf 10:16 IC2224S0230013Krull  AndreaS026000213S0270019***************0484S0280013Andrea#Krull S031001006.01.2015S032001006.01.2015S035000511160S0360003271`

### Test NSData

If I build the byte array manually using the bytes returned from bcTester, everything works out as expected and the zlib data inflates correctly. Here is how I tested:

```
let testArray = [UInt8](arrayLiteral: 0x23, 0x55, 0x54, 0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x38, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x02, 0x14, 0x1C, 0x3D, 0xE9, 0x2D, 0xCD, 0x5E, 0xC4, 0xC0, 0x56, 0xBD, 0xAE, 0x61, 0x3E, 0x54, 0xAD, 0xA1, 0xB3, 0x26, 0x33, 0xD2, 0x02, 0x14, 0x40, 0x75, 0x03, 0xD0, 0xCF, 0x9C, 0xC1, 0xF5, 0x70, 0x58, 0xBD, 0x59, 0x50, 0xA7, 0xAF, 0xC5, 0xEB, 0x0A, 0xF4, 0x74, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x32, 0x37, 0x31, 0x78, 0x9C, 0x65, 0x50, 0xCB, 0x4E, 0xC3, 0x30, 0x10, 0xE4, 0x53, 0x2C, 0x71, 0x43, 0x4A, 0xD9, 0xF5, 0x2B, 0x36, 0xB7, 0x84, 0x04, 0x52, 0x01, 0x55, 0x51, 0x40, 0x1C, 0x51, 0x01, 0x23, 0x2A, 0x42, 0x0E, 0x21, 0x15, 0x3F, 0xC7, 0x8D, 0x1F, 0x63, 0x36, 0x11, 0x52, 0x2B, 0x7C, 0xF1, 0x78, 0x76, 0x76, 0x66, 0xBD, 0xF7, 0x8F, 0x4D, 0x5D, 0x54, 0xC4, 0x44, 0xCE, 0x10, 0x05, 0xD2, 0xEB, 0x78, 0x5B, 0xAC, 0x32, 0x7B, 0xB4, 0x77, 0xC8, 0x11, 0x6B, 0x62, 0xC7, 0xD6, 0x79, 0xAA, 0xEA, 0xAA, 0x16, 0xE1, 0xB2, 0x22, 0x4D, 0xC4, 0x01, 0xAD, 0x36, 0x58, 0x61, 0xCA, 0x6B, 0x30, 0xC6, 0xE5, 0x64, 0xA0, 0xB6, 0x97, 0x0F, 0xA6, 0xA9, 0x6F, 0xD6, 0x71, 0xDF, 0xC7, 0xCF, 0x3E, 0x7F, 0x37, 0x93, 0x66, 0x8E, 0xC6, 0x71, 0xDE, 0x92, 0x4C, 0xC0, 0xE1, 0x22, 0x0D, 0xFD, 0x57, 0x7A, 0xCB, 0xEE, 0xB6, 0xCF, 0xEF, 0x69, 0x54, 0xFD, 0x66, 0x44, 0x05, 0x31, 0xD0, 0x03, 0x18, 0x01, 0x05, 0x40, 0x04, 0x70, 0x9C, 0x51, 0x46, 0xAD, 0x38, 0x49, 0x33, 0x00, 0x86, 0x20, 0xDD, 0x42, 0x88, 0x04, 0x22, 0x5F, 0xA6, 0xA1, 0xDB, 0xF6, 0x78, 0x79, 0xD4, 0x79, 0x95, 0x76, 0x1F, 0x3F, 0xDF, 0xFD, 0xE7, 0x98, 0x86, 0x16, 0xB1, 0x30, 0x0B, 0x65, 0xD6, 0x3C, 0xBD, 0x2A, 0x15, 0xCE, 0xD8, 0xAB, 0xE5, 0x79, 0x9D, 0x47, 0x7B, 0xDA, 0x34, 0x13, 0xC7, 0x34, 0x73, 0x5A, 0x6B, 0x0B, 0x35, 0x72, 0xD9, 0x5C, 0x0D, 0xBB, 0xAE, 0x53, 0xAA, 0xE8, 0x5F, 0x86, 0xB4, 0x01, 0xE9, 0x25, 0x8D, 0x0D, 0x50, 0x8E, 0x72, 0x3C, 0x39, 0x3C, 0xB2, 0x13, 0x94, 0x82, 0x74, 0xCE, 0x2D, 0xC7, 0xB3, 0x41, 0x8B, 0xED, 0x4C, 0x9F, 0xF5, 0x0B, 0xE2, 0x85, 0x6C, 0x01, 0x8C, 0xFE, 0xC7, 0xB8, 0xE9, 0x87, 0x8C, 0xD9, 0xF1, 0x90, 0x28, 0xA3, 0x73, 0xFE, 0x05, 0x6D, 0xDE, 0x5F, 0xF1)
let testData = NSData(bytes: testArray, length: testArray.count)
```

Comment: did you have luck figuring it out?

Comment: sadly, no. for now I have put a halt to development to see if iOS 10 will expose methods that facilitate this type of application. that said, if you know something, let me (and others here) know please.

Comment: iOS 11 actually has new APIs for decoding barcodes with binary content! "Added APIs to AV Foundation, Core Image, and SiriKit to support detection, decoding, and creation of barcodes with binary content." https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS_11_0.html

Comment: Given the new iOS 11 APIs, I attempted to solve this once again. Sadly, no luck. Only more questions. I posted my results in a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037418/zlib-streams-in-ios-11-vision-framework-barcodes-sometimes-decompress-sometimes

Answer (score 4):

I solved this some time ago in Xamarin/C#, but the idea is the same for Swift too. The `encodedData` and `ReadCode` methods are taken form ZXing lib. Hope it helps.

It works well for reading and decoding both "small" and "large" ticket codes, but the default Aztec reader in iOS SDK is not good enough, so in the end we went on with the reader from Manateeworks. I can see now that it did not get any better with iOS 10 SDK.

```
    public override void DidOutputMetadataObjects (AVCaptureMetadataOutput captureOutput, AVMetadataObject[] metadataObjects, AVCaptureConnection connection)
    {
        foreach (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject metadata in metadataObjects) {
            var d1 = (metadata.ValueForKey ((NSString)"_internal"));
            var d2 = (d1.ValueForKey ((NSString)"basicDescriptor"));
            var data = (d2.ValueForKey ((NSString)"BarcodeRawData"));
            var str = data.ToString ().Trim ().Trim (new [] { '<', '>' }).Replace (" ", "");


            var bitarray = new bool[str.Length * 4];
            for (var i = 0; i < str.Length / 2; i++) {
                int value = Convert.ToInt32 (str.Substring (i * 2, 2), 16);
                bitarray [i * 8 + 0] = (value & 1) > 0;
                bitarray [i * 8 + 1] = (value & 2) > 0;
                bitarray [i * 8 + 2] = (value & 4) > 0;
                bitarray [i * 8 + 3] = (value & 8) > 0;
                bitarray [i * 8 + 4] = (value & 16) > 0;
                bitarray [i * 8 + 5] = (value & 32) > 0;
                bitarray [i * 8 + 6] = (value & 64) > 0;
                bitarray [i * 8 + 7] = (value & 128) > 0;
            }
            var pabData = encodedData (bitarray);

            parent.scanFinished (true, pabData);
        }
    }


    enum ZXAztecTable
    {
        ZXAztecTableUpper,
        ZXAztecTableBinary,
        ZXAztecTableDigit
    };

    public byte[] encodedData (bool[] bitArray)
    {
        var result = new List<byte> ();
        int endIndex = bitArray.Length;
        ZXAztecTable latchTable = ZXAztecTable.ZXAztecTableUpper; // table most recently latched to
        ZXAztecTable shiftTable = ZXAztecTable.ZXAztecTableUpper; // table to use for the next read
        int index = 0;
        while (index < endIndex) {
            if (shiftTable == ZXAztecTable.ZXAztecTableBinary) {
                if (endIndex - index < 5) {
                    break;
                }
                int length = ReadCode (bitArray, index, 5);
                index += 5;
                if (length == 0) {
                    if (endIndex - index < 11) {
                        break;
                    }

                    length = ReadCode (bitArray, index, 11) + 31;
                    index += 11;
                }
                for (int charCount = 0; charCount < length; charCount++) {
                    if (endIndex - index < 8) {
                        index = endIndex;  // Force outer loop to exit
                        break;
                    }

                    byte code = (byte)ReadCode (bitArray, index, 8);
                    result.Add (code);
                    index += 8;
                }
                // Go back to whatever mode we had been in
                shiftTable = latchTable;
            } else {
                int size = shiftTable == ZXAztecTable.ZXAztecTableDigit ? 4 : 5;
                if (endIndex - index < size) {
                    break;
                }
                ReadCode (bitArray, index, size);
                index += size;
                latchTable = shiftTable;
                shiftTable = ZXAztecTable.ZXAztecTableBinary;
            }
        }
        return result.ToArray ();
    }

    public int ReadCode (bool[] bitArray, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = startIndex; i < startIndex + length; i++) {
            res <<= 1;
            if (bitArray [i]) {
                res |= 0x01;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Whew, the barcode scanner from Manateeworks costs 1000s of $ as far as I can see. That's a little steep for my pet project. Do you think there is another scanner out there that can do this? And if you'd like to share: what do you think does the iOS built-in software do "wrong"?

Comment: According to our research there is not. ZXing Aztec reader is in beta quality and comparing its capabilities to the iOS built-in scanner suggests that Apple used ZXing as their base.

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"? It just takes much more time and user's effort to align the phone with the code so it is recognized. Manatee reader works from various angles, distances, and even for partially discoloured or wrinkled codes.
If you project is non-commercial and/or open source, you can try getting a better price. There are at least 4 good Aztec reader SDKs for iOS on the market.

Answer (score 2):

Although I had the same issue while working with Data Matrix code, I assume this answer will be helpful for those who encountered the same problem.

So, we managed to retrieve raw bytes from AVMetadataReadableMachineObject via KVO ("internalBasicDescriptor" "barcodeRawData") as Data and printed its description to console, as you did in example. The bytes are not what we expect to see and e.g. we cannot produce a readable string from it (or it is not even a text). The reason is that the code was generated using a particular encoding scheme.

In my case, Data Matrix use C40, X12, Edifact, Base256... encoding schemes. In case of Data Matrix codes, you can check the table from the official documentation https://www.gs1.org/docs/barcodes/GS1_DataMatrix_Guideline.pdf (p. 50). For instance, if we convert the first byte and get 231, it indicates that the code is encoded using base256.

QR, Aztec and other codes may use the same approach of encoding data (probably not the ones I mentioned). Thus, depending of your type you should search for encoding schemes (which are, in most cases, simple math formulas converting one integer to another). Consider, that a detailed documentation of encodation schemes may be increasingly limited thought the web.

So, the bytes returned by AVMetadataObject are correct, though encoded (you should actually try to understand how).

Lastly, from iOS 11.0 you can get raw bytes in a better way:

```
if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject {
    if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr {
         let descriptor = object.descriptor {
             let rawBytes = descriptor.errorPayload
```

use .dataMatrix, .aztec, etc. instead of .qr (or you can even skip this line).

Thus, descriptor is basically CIBarcodeDescriptor, which has child classes so you can get more precise results (such as CIDataMatrixCodeDescriptor, CIQRCodeDescriptor, etc.) You can check some information on Apple Developer Website as well.