# How to decompress/inflate zlib data in a byte array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compression, zlib

Premise: I'm working on a **Swift 3** app that decodes a [certain type of barcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225276/reading-raw-bytes-from-an-aztec-barcode-via-avmetadatamachinereadablecodeobject) which stores raw zlib data. I have figured out how to read the barcode data. I have an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>`, but could produce Swift `Data` or `NSData` from it, if neccessary.

If at all possible, I'd like to use the new built-in [libcompression](https://developer.apple.com/reference/compression/1665429-data_compression) APIs to avoid external dependencies. I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34456485/3625228) by jbg, but I'm having trouble getting it to actually decompress anything (I also had to auto-convert the code to Swift 3 syntax). I feel like this is just a problem of getting the data in the correct format.

I have built a test case, but I never get a result and the loop never exits. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it a lot.

```
let array = [UInt8](arrayLiteral: 0x78, 0x9C, 0x65, 0x50, 0xCB, 0x4E, 0xC3, 0x30, 0x10, 0xE4, 0x53, 0x2C, 0x71, 0x43, 0x4A, 0xD9, 0xF5, 0x2B, 0x36, 0xB7, 0x84, 0x04, 0x52, 0x01, 0x55, 0x51, 0x40, 0x1C, 0x51, 0x01, 0x23, 0x2A, 0x42, 0x0E, 0x21, 0x15, 0x3F, 0xC7, 0x8D, 0x1F, 0x63, 0x36, 0x11, 0x52, 0x2B, 0x7C, 0xF1, 0x78, 0x76, 0x76, 0x66, 0xBD, 0xF7, 0x8F, 0x4D, 0x5D, 0x54, 0xC4, 0x44, 0xCE, 0x10, 0x05, 0xD2, 0xEB, 0x78, 0x5B, 0xAC, 0x32, 0x7B, 0xB4, 0x77, 0xC8, 0x11, 0x6B, 0x62, 0xC7, 0xD6, 0x79, 0xAA, 0xEA, 0xAA, 0x16, 0xE1, 0xB2, 0x22, 0x4D, 0xC4, 0x01, 0xAD, 0x36, 0x58, 0x61, 0xCA, 0x6B, 0x30, 0xC6, 0xE5, 0x64, 0xA0, 0xB6, 0x97, 0x0F, 0xA6, 0xA9, 0x6F, 0xD6, 0x71, 0xDF, 0xC7, 0xCF, 0x3E, 0x7F, 0x37, 0x93, 0x66, 0x8E, 0xC6, 0x71, 0xDE, 0x92, 0x4C, 0xC0, 0xE1, 0x22, 0x0D, 0xFD, 0x57, 0x7A, 0xCB, 0xEE, 0xB6, 0xCF, 0xEF, 0x69, 0x54, 0xFD, 0x66, 0x44, 0x05, 0x31, 0xD0, 0x03, 0x18, 0x01, 0x05, 0x40, 0x04, 0x70, 0x9C, 0x51, 0x46, 0xAD, 0x38, 0x49, 0x33, 0x00, 0x86, 0x20, 0xDD, 0x42, 0x88, 0x04, 0x22, 0x5F, 0xA6, 0xA1, 0xDB, 0xF6, 0x78, 0x79, 0xD4, 0x79, 0x95, 0x76, 0x1F, 0x3F, 0xDF, 0xFD, 0xE7, 0x98, 0x86, 0x16, 0xB1, 0x30, 0x0B, 0x65, 0xD6, 0x3C, 0xBD, 0x2A, 0x15, 0xCE, 0xD8, 0xAB, 0xE5, 0x79, 0x9D, 0x47, 0x7B, 0xDA, 0x34, 0x13, 0xC7, 0x34, 0x73, 0x5A, 0x6B, 0x0B, 0x35, 0x72, 0xD9, 0x5C, 0x0D, 0xBB, 0xAE, 0x53, 0xAA, 0xE8, 0x5F, 0x86, 0xB4, 0x01, 0xE9, 0x25, 0x8D, 0x0D, 0x50, 0x8E, 0x72, 0x3C, 0x39, 0x3C, 0xB2, 0x13, 0x94, 0x82, 0x74, 0xCE, 0x2D, 0xC7, 0xB3, 0x41, 0x8B, 0xED, 0x4C, 0x9F, 0xF5, 0x0B, 0xE2, 0x85, 0x6C, 0x01, 0x8C, 0xFE, 0xC7, 0xB8, 0xE9, 0x87, 0x8C, 0xD9, 0xF1, 0x90, 0x28, 0xA3, 0x73, 0xFE, 0x05, 0x6D, 0xDE, 0x5F, 0xF1)

let streamPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<compression_stream>.allocate(capacity: 1)
var stream = streamPtr.pointee
var status: compression_status

status = compression_stream_init(&stream, COMPRESSION_STREAM_DECODE, COMPRESSION_ZLIB)
stream.src_ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(array)
stream.src_size = array.count

let dstBufferSize: size_t = 4096
let dstBufferPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: dstBufferSize)
stream.dst_ptr = dstBufferPtr
stream.dst_size = dstBufferSize

let decompressedData = NSMutableData()

repeat {
    status = compression_stream_process(&stream, 0)
    switch status {
    case COMPRESSION_STATUS_OK:

        if stream.dst_size == 0 {
            decompressedData.append(dstBufferPtr, length: dstBufferSize)
            stream.dst_ptr = dstBufferPtr
            stream.dst_size = dstBufferSize
        }
    case COMPRESSION_STATUS_END:
        if stream.dst_ptr > dstBufferPtr {
            decompressedData.append(dstBufferPtr, length: stream.dst_ptr - dstBufferPtr)
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
    while status == COMPRESSION_STATUS_OK

compression_stream_destroy(&stream)

print("done")
print(decompressedData)
```

Comment: I have written my own followup on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037418/zlib-stream-in-ios-11-vision-framework-barcodes-sometimes-decompress-sometimes

Comment: Hint: the sample data I use in this example is probably an invalid zlib stream, so all decompression libs bug out. I will update this post with an actual answer if I manage to solve this during my lifetime.