# Reading QR-Code with null byte in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, qr-code, avcapture

I'm trying to scan a QR-Code containing a null byte (\x00) with AVFoundation.

The problem is that AVMetaDataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue only returns the data before the null byte.

For example when QR-Code data is "ABC\x00abc" the stringValue only returns "ABC"

Is there a way to get the complete String?

I already found this question: [Read binary QR Code with AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429480/read-binary-qr-code-with-avfoundation) but I'm not sure if the "BarcodeRawData" is what I need or how to convert this Data to a String.

Comment: We encountered the same issue while reading DataMatrix with Objective C.
The issue is probably related to the null (`/x00`) character that is also used in C to identify the end of a C string.