# Swift 4 - AVMetadataObject stringValue has incomplete information when reading pdf417 barcode

Tags: ios, swift, barcode-scanner, swift4, pdf417

I'm trying to read information from a barcode type PDF417 with the AVFoundation library.

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject {
        print(metadataObj.stringValue)//prints 0357379329
    }
}
```

At the point of execution for the **didOutput** method in the "AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate", I can capture the **AVMetadataObject** and its **stringValue**; nevertheless the stringValue has not complete information contained in the barcode, it generates something like this:

0357379329

I can see more information when I use paid applications like [BlinkId](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-ios).

According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429480/read-binary-qr-code-with-avfoundation), I tried to use the "_internal.basicDescriptor" method:

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject {
        if let basic_descriptor = metadataObj.value(forKeyPath: "_internal.basicDescriptor") as? NSObject {
            if let barcodeRawData = basic_descriptor.value(forKeyPath: "BarcodeRawData") as? NSData {
                let barcode_raw_data_length = barcodeRawData.length
                let memory_layout = MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size
                let count = barcode_raw_data_length / memory_layout
                var array = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: count)//Array con 1050 elementos. Cada elemento es igual a cero
                barcodeRawData.getBytes(&array, length:count * memory_layout)
                let data_character = array.reduce("", { $0 + String(format: "%c", $1)})
                print(data_character)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

data_character prints a string with something like this that I don't know how to interpret:

ÍH*ÕÛ+ÝY-<4mI ËÇ;ÚÖ
ÂÿûJhiòþ
^HT¶î`èm½C3&îð`Ü,Feæ»0æ¤öc$¯#m,WÆç4Pá$ÑñÃ¼0njtYÜ0U¼ÇçA°'£aR.)9
Êq3uúù7=,~mV*½Q*ý;áu½7ó&æiTÝJ¸ËõÚAZähc¨à¼Ø²BsÇKZÖ*ëu-Õß/³©îprX×Ijßçól{¡¿ý...

I would like to know any of these:

1. How can I get the AVMetadataObject stringValue with the whole info?
2. How can I interpret the string generated with the "_internal.basicDescriptor"?
3. Is there another method to get info from a pdf417 in swift 4?

Thanks!